# JButton inside JTable inside JTable inside JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, layout, jtable, jtabbedpane

So the code behind it is quite massive.
I have JTabbedPane with a Tab for each table(inside JSCrollPane ) and a Summary table which contains tables that uses the same models as models in the tabs. So when I add rows to the table everything renders properly. When one of the tables has its data changed everything renders OK , except the JButtons (the button in the first row always renders) . Clicking on the line fixes it , even if it changes again the button does not disappear.

When data changes I only fireDataChanged() for the model of contained tables, the model does fire repaint on the contained tables and the container table.

Comment: Posting your code would help here, if possible in a shortened [sscce](http://sscce.org/) format

Comment: You are saying you use JTable as a renderer in a JTable? Post screen and SSCEE to get better help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each swing component can be in only one container. The problem comes if you try to put into two Jpanels, if you do that with 2 Jtables that use the same instance of a model ,what happens is originally everything renders properly , but will break as soon as you activate the component(button). It will stop rendering in the table where you pressed it , in some cases both.